# How to populate list of items from Object without instantiating

Tags: java, spring-boot, mapstruct

I have a list of objects populated and I need to populate more attributes from a Object.

Considering using mapperstruct and I can't modifying previous atributes of Objects from a target list.

```java
// type for obj in list target
public class ObjectExampleA {

    private String id;
    private String firstAttr;
    private String secondAttr;
    private String thirdAttr;
}

// target list
// List<ObjectExampleA> listTarget;

// at this point considering an elements in list like this...
// {"id":1, "firstAttr":"blue", "secondAttr":"black", "thirdAttr": null}
// {"id":2, "firstAttr":"gray", "secondAttr":"red", "thirdAttr": null}

// source obj 
public class ObjectExampleB {

    private String thirdAttr;
}
```

```java
// I need to populate all thirdAttr atribute of all elements in listTarget from ObjectExampleB.thirdAttr value


@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface ExampleMapper {

    void populateThirdAttrInList(@MappingTarget List<ObjectExampleA> listTarget, ObjectExampleB objectExampleB);
}
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear, could you please elaborate?

Comment: I need to populate only the thirdAttr attribute of all targetList objects, with the value that is in ObjectExampleB.thirdAttr, without changing the objects already in this list.

Comment: "thirdAttr" has a private modifier, so you can't access it. Consider using Reflection to achieve what you seek.

Comment: the getters() and setters() exists, but it's just example

Answer (score 1):

Performing an update of elements of a collection is not always trivial. However, your case can be solved inn a simple way by doing an update of `ObjectExampleA`.

E.g.

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface ExampleMapper {

    default void populateThirdAttrInList(@MappingTarget List<ObjectExampleA> listTarget, ObjectExampleB objectExampleB) {
        for(ObjectExampleA exampleA: listTarget) {
            populateThirdAttr(exampleA, objectExampleB);
        }
    }

    void populateThirdAttr(@MappingTarget ObjectExampleA exampleA, ObjectExampleB exampleB);
}
```